# How to Count a Double Value Of Array In JavaScript By Using Just Array Methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Hi there,**

*I've been given a task:*

[image: ARRAY TASK]

And here is what I have tried so far:

```js
var myArray = [1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1];


document.writeln("myArray elements<br/>");
document.writeln(myArray + "<br/>");
document.writeln("myArray has " + myArray.length + " elements" + "<br/>");
document.writeln("My Array sorted: <br/>");
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
});;
document.writeln(myArray + "<br/>");
document.writeln("First Occurrence of number " + "?" + " in myArray Sorted is at index: " + myArray.indexOf(1) + "<br/>");
document.writeln("First Occurrence of number " + "?" + " in myArray Sorted is at index: " + myArray.indexOf(2) + "<br/>");
document.writeln("First Occurrence of number " + "?" + " in myArray Sorted is at index: " + myArray.indexOf(3) + "<br/>");
document.writeln("First Occurrence of number " + "?" + " in myArray Sorted is at index: " + myArray.indexOf(4) + "<br/>");
document.writeln("First Occurrence of number " + "?" + " in myArray Sorted is at index: " + myArray.indexOf(5) + "<br/>");
document.writeln("myArray contains " + "?" + " occurrence of number " + "?" + "<br/>");
document.writeln("myArray contains " + "?" + " occurrence of number " + "?" + "<br/>");
document.writeln("myArray contains " + "?" + " occurrence of number " + "?" + "<br/>");
document.writeln("myArray contains " + "?" + " occurrence of number " + "?" + "<br/>");
document.writeln("myArray contains " + "?" + " occurrence of number " + "?" + "<br/>");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Task 2 with Arrays</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Task 2 with Arrays</h1>



</body>

</html>
```

Where the: **? mark** is where I've stuck.

**I can only use the:**

- length property,
- toString()
- sort()
- indexOf()

**Please note no loops, conditional statements allowed.**

Please, does anyone can help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: is `lastIndexOf` allowed?

Comment: If you can't use `lastIndexOf`, you could sort the array in reverse order and then use `indexOf`. Then do a little bit of math with the indexes and the `length` to find out how many of a specific number is in the array.

Comment: It is not clear from the question what can be hard-coded. Is the 1 in the phrase *"First Occurrence of number 1 in myArray Sorted is at index:"* part of the fixed text? Is the fact that there are exactly five such phrases predefined? I suppose so, as with the restrictions it is impossible to make that dynamic.

Comment: I don't think so that I'm allowed to use a "lastIndexOf". Because from the instruction as you can see that it saying we have to ONLY use: length property,
toString()
sort()
indexOf()

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray = [1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1];


document.writeln("myArray elements<br/>");
document.writeln(myArray + "<br/>");
document.writeln("myArray has " + myArray.length + " elements" + "<br/>");
document.writeln("My Array sorted: <br/>");
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
});;
document.writeln(myArray + "<br/>");
document.writeln("First Occurrence of number " + "1" + " in myArray Sorted is at index: " + myArray.indexOf(1) + "<br/>");
document.writeln("First Occurrence of number " + "2" + " in myArray Sorted is at index: " + myArray.indexOf(2) + "<br/>");
document.writeln("First Occurrence of number " + "3" + " in myArray Sorted is at index: " + myArray.indexOf(3) + "<br/>");
document.writeln("First Occurrence of number " + "4" + " in myArray Sorted is at index: " + myArray.indexOf(4) + "<br/>");
document.writeln("First Occurrence of number " + "5" + " in myArray Sorted is at index: " + myArray.indexOf(5) + "<br/>");
document.writeln("myArray contains " + (myArray.indexOf(2)-myArray.indexOf(1)) + " occurrence of number " + 1 + "<br/>");
document.writeln("myArray contains " + (myArray.indexOf(3)-myArray.indexOf(2)) + " occurrence of number " + 2 + "<br/>");
document.writeln("myArray contains " + (myArray.indexOf(4)-myArray.indexOf(3)) + " occurrence of number " + 3 + "<br/>");
document.writeln("myArray contains " + (myArray.indexOf(5)-myArray.indexOf(4)) + " occurrence of number " + 4 + "<br/>");
document.writeln("myArray contains " + (myArray.length-myArray.indexOf(5)) + " occurrence of number " + 5 + "<br/>");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Task 2 with Arrays</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Task 2 with Arrays</h1>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tip: If the array is correctly sorted the first occurrence of 2 is counting all 1.

```
myArray.indexOf(2) - myArray.indexOf(1)
```

is counting all occurrences of 1.

Just do some simple math to find where and how many there are of the other numbers.

With the tools you're given, I don't think there's a way to dynamically find all unique numbers in the array, you'll need to hardcode them.

Comment: Your right that the problem as I'm not allowed to use any loops or conditional statement. But the task should be completed as from the picture provided above.I really appreciate your help and time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the first occurrences of all the numbers in the sorted array. So you can do simple subtraction to get the difference between the first occurrence index for each two adjacent numbers.

Comment: The subtraction could be as an Option but as you can see it's not clear if I can do like that it's just saying that I can't use loops and conditional statements. But I will give a try as you said it might work, but now sure if it's going to be counted as the Right Answer from their point of view =)